# Java string class char array

Tags: java, string

```
 public String(String original) {
this.value = original.value;
this.hash = original.hash;
 }
```

How is string being converted to char array?

In the above code, original.value is a char array. How is the string being converted to char array here?

```
  private final char value[];
```

value is only declared, not intantiated here.

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.toCharArray%28%29

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: In the above code, original.value is a char array. How is the string being converted to char array here?

Comment: Is this a serious question? Did you search for "java string to char array"? Was the search result empty? Did you look at the Javadoc? Did you anything before asking the question (which will be closed soon) here? And what you showed is just a copy constructor of the String class of Java. Any String object wraps an array of chars. Not sure what you're asking for...

Answer (score 1):

> In the above code, original.value is a char array. How is the string being converted to char array here?

The String isn't being converted to a char array!

The `original.value` char array is the part of the *internal representation* of the original string.  It is a `private` field.

No conversion is happening.  No conversion is necessary.

> ```
> private final char value[];
> ```
>
> Value is only declared, not initialized here.

Correct.  The initialization is performed by the String constructors.  If you look at the constructors, you will see that they all assign a `char[]` reference to `value`.

Answer (score -1):

Initialize array,

```
private final char value[]= new char[original.length()];
```

then iterate over string and add it to char array:

```
for(int i=0;i<original.length();i++){
    value[i]=original.charAt(i);
}
```

Here you are...